# Can't get HTML inside tag using regex (match)

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chrocwL7/)
I'm trying to get the html inside the `<app>` tag, but can't seem to get it working. How can I fix it? The regex I am using is `.match(/<app.*>(.*?)<\/app>/)[1];`

Comment: why don't you using `.find('app')` so you can search in the parsed form, instead in string content

Comment: Or `document.getElementsByTagName("app")[0].innerHTML`?

Comment: Can't I'm doing this on server side.

Comment: Next time asking a question, please add more details and show what you've already tried or ruled out.

Answer (score 1):

That's because [`.`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) matches everything except for newlines, but you want to match everything. Use `[\s\S]` instead. Check it here: https://jsfiddle.net/vumcgger/

Also, never parse html with regex (unless you really need to): [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Thanks, yeah I'm doing it inside node, having to scrape some content and extract a few things. Thanks that works great.